# Overloading abstract method causes unnecessary implementation in Java

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, overloading, abstract-class

I have the following interface:

```
public interface DataExporter {
    MultipartFile export() throws IOException;
}
```

And the following abstract class inherits from the interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractDataExporter<T> implements DataExporter {
    
    @Override
    public MultipartFile export() throws IOException {
        final Iterable<T> entities = getEntities();
        // ...
    }

    protected abstract Iterable<T> getEntities();
}
```

Then I implement `export` and `getEntities` methods as shown below:

```
public class ProductExporter extends AbstractDataExporter<ProductDTO> {

    @Override
    protected Iterable<ProductDTO> getEntities() {
        //
    }
}
```

Everything i working without any problem and I call the export method from Controller as shown below:

```
private final ProductExporter productExporter;

public ResponseEntity<Resource> exportProduct() throws IOException {
    final MultipartFile multipartFile = productExporter.export();
    //
}
```

My problem is that: When I need another exporter class e.g. CategoryExporter that takes a parameter e.g. an `UUID`, then how should I overload the `export` and `getEntities` methods properly? I overloaded by adding new methods that takes parameter, but in this case all the new methods are also needed to be added ProductExporter unnecessarily. So, how to fix that problem?

```
// ??? what about passing parameter:
private final CategoryExporter categoryExporter ;

public ResponseEntity<Resource> exportCategory(UUID uuid) throws IOException {
    final MultipartFile multipartFile = categoryExporter.export(uuid);
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasonable approaches here:

1. Don't have a common `DataExporter` interface. The client anyway needs to know the more-specific type of the exporter in order to call it with the appropriate arguments.
2. Give `DataExporter` a type parameter, and give its `export` method a parameter of that type. `ProductExporter` can then be a `DataExporter<Void>`, and its `export` method simply takes `null`, while `CategoryExporter` can be a `DataExporter<String>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for good explanations. For the 2nd approach, I think it may be a problem if I have multiple arguments, but still may be used  for 2 UUID values e.g.  `DataExporter<UUID, UUID>`. Is that true?

Comment: Would you mind posting implementation examples for both of 2 approaches using my code above? Thanks in advance.